# "if (MouseEvent.CLICK = true) " error in Actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

These are the two errors;

> 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Boolean to an unrelated
> type String.
>
> 1049: Illegal assignment to a variable specified as
> constant.

I want to basically set it so, if mouse is click

the -y speed of symbol helicopter = variable 'speed'

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be `==` in comparison instead of `=` operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This test doesn't mean anything: `MouseEvent.CLICK` is a constant and its value is **always** `"click"`. So `(MouseEvent.CLICK)` will always be `true` (testing a string returns true if this string is not null).

To check if the mouse is down, you should write something like that:

```
var mouseDown:Boolean;
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);


function onMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  mouseDown = true;
}

function onMouseUp(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  mouseDown = false;
}

function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
{
  if (mouseDown)
  {
    helicopter.y += speed;
  }
  else
  {
    //maybe fall?
  }
}
```